# How to use flask-caching in my structure of project

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache, flask-caching

My code structure. I tried but kept getting error cannot import name 'caching'. I guess my method isn't correct as caching will not have app initiation when I import caching in external file.

```
xyz
  -app.py
  -run.py
  -urls
    -v2.py
  -resource
    -views.py
  -external.py
```

### run.py

```
from app import create_app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    career_app = create_app()
    career_app.run(host=HOST,
                   port=PORT,
                   debug=True)
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
caching = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
def create_app():
    """Create web app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_app(app)
    caching.init_app(app)
    setup_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

### external.py

```
from app import caching
```

### v1.py

```
v2_api.add_resource(UserConfigView, '/user/config',
                    endpoint='user_config_view')
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple factory app setup

ext.py

```
from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache()
```

app.py

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    register_extensions(app)
    ...

def register_extensions(app):
    cache.init_app(app, config=settings.params.CACHE_CONFIG)
```